# Standard Matrix transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the matrix transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$T(x, y, z) = (–4x + 3y + z, \,\, 2x – 5y,\,\, 6y + 7z).$$

Find the standard matrix for $T$, and use that matrix to
find $T(1, –3).$

My solution:
$T(X, Y, Z) =[-4x+3y +z, 2x-5y, 6y+7z]$
which yields $ x[-4,2,0] + y[3,-5,6] +z[1,0,7].$

Which I found that the standard matrix for T is $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -4 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 &-5& 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 7 \end{array}\right)$$

Is this correct?

However I am confused about how to use it to find $T(1,-3)$.

Comment: You are sure that it is $T$ at $(1,-3)$ and not at a point with three coordinates?

Comment: Yes you are correct, there seems to have been a typo on the sheet, Its suppose to be T(1,-3,4)

Comment: SO how would I then use the matrix to find T(1,-3,4)? set it equal to the matrix and row reduce it to find the values?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You matrix is correct. You indeed get
$$
A = \pmatrix{-4 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 7}.
$$
If you want to find $T$ at a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, then you simply perform the matrix multiplication
$$
A\pmatrix{x_0\\ y_0\\ z_0} = \pmatrix{-4 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 7}\pmatrix{x_0\\ y_0\\ z_0}.
$$
For example:
$$
T(1, -3, 4) = \pmatrix{-4 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 7}\pmatrix{1\\ -3\\ 4} = \pmatrix{-9 \\ .. \\ ..}
$$